# Adding macro button to trigger a specific Macro

Tags: ms-office, office-automation, ribbonx

Whenever I add a custom Macro button to the Quick Access Toolbar , it is a generic Macro window invocation button. What I want is that if I click on the button, a specific Macro should directly start running. As of now there are 2-3 steps before I do that. First of all I click on the icon on the quick access toolbar , another small drop down shows up unnecessarily as shown here ( not sure why Add Ons is appearing here, I never added)

[image]

Secondly, if I click on the bigger Macros icon in the dropdown again , I get a dialog box where I have to choose macro from a list. I don't want to go through all this. As soon as I click on the button, a specific macro (I should be able to configure name of the macro) should start. I know there is a shortcut available for triggering a specific macro but I prefer a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to configure QAT buttons manually you may consider developing a COM based add-in instead. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2022) for more information.

To customize the ribbon UI you can use the designer provided by VSTO, see [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using the Ribbon Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-the-ribbon-designer?view=vs-2022).